# Rails 6.0.4 config.ru undefined_method load_server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know why I'm getting this error config.ru undefined method load_server when I try to start puma

Answer (score 3):

Try checking your config.ru file for a line that contains that method something like `Rails.application.load_server` and comment/remove it.

Restart your server